# JavaScript next div is revealed after selecting a yes/no checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a quiz where each question gets revealed after the Yes/No checkbox is selected from the previous one, I've got this working to an extent, but if you select 'Yes' and then 'No' the second question wont reveal because the 'No' is triggering a toggle function to hide the question.

here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
 });        
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="A1">
   <input type="checkbox" id="A1" name="q1" value="Yes">&nbsp;Yes</input><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="A1N" name="q1" value="No">&nbsp;No</input>
</div>

<div is="A2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="q1r" value="Yes" id="Q1R">&nbsp;Yes</input><br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="q1r" value="No">&nbsp;No</input>
</div>
```

**toggle**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var par = $('#A2');
  $(par).hide();      
  $('#A1').click(function(e) {
      $(par).slideToggle('slow');        
  });
    $('#A1N').click(function(e) {
      $(par).slideToggle('slow');        
  });
});
</script>
```

What is the solution to this? or have I maybe overcomplicated it?

Comment: You have multiple elements with `id="A1"` - an ID should only ever match a single element.   What's likely happening is click is binding to both the div and the checkbox - so you get *two* events and it hides+closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because slideToggle both hides and reveals elements whereas slideDown just reveals them

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.slideToggle()` use `.slideDown()`